# How to use SyntaxNet Output with another RNN algorithm

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, nlp, recurrent-neural-network, syntaxnet

currently I’m building an NLU utilizing ​Arabic Language I’m using SyntaxNet, and I will use the RNN as an algorithm of machine learning for text classification and chatbot.

My Question is **how can I link between the output of SyntaxNet and RNN ??**